# AngularJS service injection incorrect/different when called from a $timeout or AJAX call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a directive with injected providers (with private variables) - sample code below and in http://jsfiddle.net/jycchoong/BmaQD/3/. The provider injected is as expected when (a) its method is invoked inline in the directive's link function, or (b) through a $broadcast invoked in the directive's link function. However, when (c) it is invoked via a $timeout (or in the case of my code, $watch after an AJAX call dirties the watched object), the provider injected is associated with the last instantiation of the directive.

You can see (c) occurring in the output (first line, third sentence). Whereas in (a) or (b) (first two sentences in the output), "Instance 1" is returned from the provider, for (c), "Instance 2" is returned. The $scope itself is correct (see $scope.$id in the output, so we're in the correct directive instance), but the provider instance is for the last directive.

Any suggestions for whether I'm doing something wrong or should I be structuring the code differently? For a broader explanation of the pattern I'm pursuing (which you do not have to read), have a look at the background notes after the code fragments below, if there are suggestions for different ways of achieving the overall objective.

Thanks for any help!!!

PS. This is not a closure issue. All scenarios (a), (b) and (c) have the same local/closure visibility in the log function.

HTML:

```
<div my-directive id="Instance 1"></div>
<div my-directive id="Instance 2"></div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['myModule']);
angular.module('myModule',[])
.directive('myDirective', function (myProvider, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function ($scope, element) {
            element.text('');
            var log = function ($event, eventData) {
                element.text(element.text()+'For source "'+($event ? eventData.source : 'Inline')
                    + '", scope id = ' + $scope.$id + ' with provider "' + myProvider.externalFn()
                    + '". ');
            };
            myProvider.init(element.attr('id'));
            // Inline
            log();
            $scope.$on('myEvent', log);
            // Invoke broadcast inline
            $scope.$broadcast('myEvent', {source: 'Broadcast Inline'});
            $timeout(function() {
                // Invoke broadcast in $timeout or from $watch
                $scope.$broadcast('myEvent', {source: 'Broadcast Delayed'});
            }, 1000, false);
        }
    };
})
.provider('myProvider', function () {
    var internalVar;
    return {
        $get: function () {
            return {
                init: function (value) {
                    internalVar = value;
                },
                externalFn: function () {
                    return internalVar;
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Output:

```
For source "Inline", scope id = 003 with provider "Instance 1". For source "Broadcast Inline", scope id = 003 with provider "Instance 1". For source "Broadcast Delayed", scope id = 003 with provider "Instance 2".
For source "Inline", scope id = 004 with provider "Instance 2". For source "Broadcast Inline", scope id = 004 with provider "Instance 2". For source "Broadcast Delayed", scope id = 004 with provider "Instance 2".
```

### Background

What I'm looking to do isn't, I expect, that unusual. I'm keeping the directive code and the provider code separate. I chose the provider because the service needs to be able to store its own private variables, and each instance of the provider/directive combo has different values in the private variables. This allows different developers to be working on services vs. directives (or to allow different variants of a particular service to be injected). Everything was working great until I had to get my data updated from an AJAX call and all of a sudden, the injected provider was no longer the one I was expecting.

An obvious workaround is to have the $scope passed into the provider - as you would have seen in the code above, the right $scope is available. That's kind of ugly and breaks the benefits of the pattern. I certainly don't want the provider developer fiddling around with the whole $scope. Another solution is to create a $scope.myProvider object and then only pass that down to the provider to work with (and store everything in) so that the rest of the $scope isn't visible, but this seems like a bit of a hack.

Comments welcomed...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figured it out. Rookie AngularJS mistake. Services are not traditional classes. You can't instantiate them to have different private variables for each directive that they are injected into. There's only one "instantiation". If there's a need to have different variable values per directive, you must stick those variables into the $scope (each directive will have a different $scope). It takes a bit of getting used to given it's a substantial change in thinking from traditional OO classes.

The solution is to push the $scope into the provider and if there's a desire to limit the provider's "scope" to avoid mucking up the rest of the scope, do something like the following (http://jsfiddle.net/jycchoong/BmaQD/5/). It's self policing (in the provider) though. I would love to know if there's a better way...

```
.provider('myProvider', function () {
    var myProviderScope;
    var setMyProviderScope = function($scope) {
        myProviderScope = $scope.myProvider;
    };
    return {
        $get: function () {
            return {
                init: function ($scope, value) {
                    if (!$scope.myProvider) $scope.myProvider = {};
                    setMyProviderScope($scope);
                    myProviderScope.val = value;
                },
                externalFn: function ($scope) {
                    setMyProviderScope($scope);
                    return myProviderScope.val;
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```